# Absolute positioned div won't take the rest of the width

Tags: html, css

I have the html like this :

```
<div class="addToCardButton">
  <div class="offerButtons">
    <button type="reset" class="btnReset">R</button> 
    <input type="number" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="Your offer..." class="offerInput">
    <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">S</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css is as follows :

```
.addToCardButton{
  width: 370px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px
}

.offerButtons{
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

.btnReset, .btnSubmit, .offerInput{
  position: absolute;
}

.btnReset{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
}

.btnSubmit{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  right: 0;
}

.offerInput{
 position:absolute;
 left: 35px;
 right: 35px;
 height: 24px;
}
```

Thus, what I want is that buttons have fixed width (30px) and that input takes the rest of the width.

I tried to do it with position absolute, but I get something like this :

[image]

But I want something like this :

[image]

Thus in my case the input doesn't take the rest of the width. What am I doing wrong?

I tried also with

```
width: calc(100% - 70px);
```

And that worked in all good browsers, but in Edge and IE not.

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/723x7nq0/).

Comment: If you care about mobile clients and different resolutions you can't achieve that with position absolute without making changes to width of input in media at all breakpoints. I would recommend flexbox as @SvenL suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really care about IE and other old browsers:

```css
.addToCardButton {
    width: 370px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px
}

.offerButtons {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.input-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 31px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btnReset {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.btnSubmit {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.offerInput {
    height: 24px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="addToCardButton">
  <div class="offerButtons">
    <button type="reset" class="btnReset">R</button> 
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input type="number" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="Your offer..." class="offerInput">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">S</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remember to vendor prefix `box-sizing` also. (`-moz-box-sizing`)

Answer (score 2):

With **Flexbox** you could even simplify and optimize your code to the following

**HTML**

```
<div class="addToCardButton">
    <button type="reset" class="btnReset">R</button>
    <input type="number" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="Your offer..." class="offerInput">
    <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">S</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.addToCardButton {
  width: 370px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

.btnReset,
.btnSubmit {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.offerInput {
  height: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```css
.addToCardButton {
  width: 370px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
}
.btnReset,
.btnSubmit {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.offerInput {
  height: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="addToCardButton">
  <button type="reset" class="btnReset">R</button>
  <input type="number" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="Your offer..." class="offerInput">
  <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">S</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it work in IE and Edge? My experience with the shit of IE and flex isn't good.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox In Edge it works properly, but if you care about old IE it doesn't, however almost no one use IE now and Microsoft doesn't support IE10, so we can too.

Comment: @AlanMroczek If you ask me, I'd sent to jail those who use IE ;) , but my boss does not share my opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your `HTML` as well? handling `width`, `margin` and `padding` of `input` is harder than `div`, so my recommendation is to wrap the `input` into another `div` get the `width` you need and then set the `input` 100% width. Something like this.

```css
.addToCardButton{
  width: 370px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px
}
.inputContainer{
  padding: 0 38px 0 0px;
  position:absolute;
  left:35px;
  right:0;
}
.offerButtons{
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

.btnReset, .btnSubmit, .offerInput{
  position: absolute;
}

.btnReset{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
}

.btnSubmit{
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  right: 0;
}

.offerInput{
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="addToCardButton">
  <div class="offerButtons">
    <button type="reset" class="btnReset">R</button> 
    <div class="inputContainer"><input type="number" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="Your offer..." class="offerInput"></div>
    <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">S</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnb0edp2/1/

Answer (score 0):

`.offerButtons` doesn't have height that's why the position relative is not taking its width or height. Try making its `height:100%`. See this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/723x7nq0/4/

```
.offerButtons{
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
}

.offerInput{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 24px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the width of `.addToCardButton` is generated dinamicaly and what if it  has for example `width: 900px`. Then is the spacing between input and buttons too big.

Comment: @Boky the spacing between the buttons is bigger since the `input` has only 80% of width it.

Comment: I know that. But can I avoid that? Is there any possibility to have the same spacing?

Comment: @Boky yah you can just use this width on the input. `width: calc(100% - 80px);`

Comment: I used it, but like I said in the question, it gave me a strange results in Edge and IE.

Comment: @Boky It seems good to me. `calc` is working on IE and Edge i don't know why is this a problem to you..

Comment: I first did it with calc, but it didn't worked, and now I need to find another way.